# How do I refer to a JAR built in the same Buildr buildfile?

Tags: scala, jar, buildr

I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA to build my project, but I want to move away from it to break the dependency on this particular IDE.  [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org) looks like a nice option since 1) it is simple, and 2) I already know Ruby.

My IDEA project, which is for a Java library, currently looks something like this:

```
/
    /src/...
    /sample_applications/
```

I can build my library as a JAR with a target like this with no issues:

```
define 'my_library' do
  project.version = '0.0.1'
  package(:jar)
end
```

But I'd like to provide build targets for the sample applications--which depend on `my_library`--using the same buildfile.  If I create another target like so:

```
sample_layout = Layout.new
sample_layout[:source, :main, :scala] = 'sample_programs/simple_program.scala'
define 'simple_program', :layout => sample_layout do
  project.version = '0.0.1'
  package(:jar)
end
```

`simple_program-0.0.1.jar` is compiled just fine, but the `my_library` JAR is not included.  If I include it by modifying the above definition to:

```
define 'simple_program', :layout => sample_layout do
  project.version = '0.0.1'
  package(:jar).path("lib").tap do |p|
    p.include artifact('my_library').to_s
  end
end
```

Then I get an error like:
    RuntimeError : Missing artifact identifier for {:group=>"my_library"}

How can I refer to a JAR I made earlier in another project in the same buildfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple issue, you just need to tell Buildr that the package task requires building the jar from the other project:

```
package(:jar).include( project('my_library').package(:jar), :as => "lib/my_library.jar" )
```